# create a item list in a cart with a list (Flutter Web)

Tags: list, flutter, listview, dart, flutter-web

I tried to create a list of items in an order cart. But it shows only the first item in the list....

Here is my code:

.......

```
class CartItem {
  String name;
  String quantity;
  String price;

  CartItem({
    this.name,
    this.quantity,
    this.price,
  });
}

List<CartItem> cartItem = [];

var _quantity = TextEditingController();
```

........

```
Widget cartList() {
  if (cartItem.length != 0) {
    for (var item in cartItem) {
      return new Text('${item.name}');
    }
  }
  return Text('Nothing in Cart');
}
```

.......

```
RaisedButton(
                    elevation: 1,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    onPressed: () {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext contex) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            content: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text('Your Order List'),
                                Container(
                                  child: cartList(),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Conferm Order',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                    ),
                  ),
```

I also tried with listview.builder but I have failed. It gives me some error. Something like "Assertion failed" or "Rendering" type error.

```
Widget cartList() {
  if (cartItem.length != 0) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: cartItem.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(cartItem[index].name);
      },
    );
  }
  return Text('Nothing in Cart');
}
```

this is the error when I try with Listiew.builder:

The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
RenderIntrinsicWidth#3fbd2 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
creator: IntrinsicWidth ← Semantics ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ←
_InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#eb4f8 ink renderer] ←
NotificationListener ←
CustomPaint ← _ShapeBorderPaint ← PhysicalShape ← _MaterialInterior ← Material ←
ConstrainedBox ←
⋯
parentData:  (can use size)
constraints: BoxConstraints(280.0<=w<=711.0, 0.0<=h<=343.0)
size: MISSING
stepWidth: null
stepHeight: null
This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
child: RenderFlex#22eec NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
child 1: RenderPadding#42cc4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
child: RenderFlex#09e2b NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
child 1: RenderParagraph#afac8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
text: TextSpan
child 2: RenderRepaintBoundary#14459 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
child: RenderCustomPaint#ddfde NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

And this:

Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed:
file:~flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/mouse_tra
cking.dart:392:12

Comment: `ListView.builder` is the way to go. `return` statements exit the function, they don't magically create a `List` our of multiple `return`s. Please share the *specific* error with your `ListView.builder`.

Comment: it shows this: `Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed:
file:/~flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/mouse_tra
cking.dart:392:12`

Comment: That's a separate error, hence why it say "**Another** exception". Please show the exception specifically for `ListView.builder`.

Comment: Please delete these comments and post it as an edit in the question.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: This is a layout issue. You're not providing size constraints to widgets that need them.

Comment: I've tried with size constraints also. but unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: You likely didn't add constraints where it's necessary.

Comment: Ok, forget about ListView.builder. If I want to go with my first widget method which is `for(var item in cartItem)`. What will be the way?

Comment: Instead of `return`ing, create a `List`.

Comment: Use `ListView.builder` and follow @HosseinYousefi's excellent answer.

Comment: Thanks to you also. It works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first off, the moment you `return` in almost any programming language, you go out of the function. So you won't get a list but only a single `Text` widget.

And about the `ListView.builder`, you're missing the `.name` (if you want to show more things like price you have to use another widget or concatenate them into a single string since Text only accepts a `String`):

```
Widget cartList() {
  if (cartItem.length != 0) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: cartItem.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(cartItem[index].name);
      },
    );
  }
  return Text('Nothing in Cart');
}
```

Instead of `Text` widget you could potentially use [`ListTile`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) which has placeholders for many Text widgets usually useful for lists.

Now for the layout error, the simplest fix would be to add `height` and `width` properties for the `Container` containing your `cartList`:

```
return AlertDialog(
  content: Column(
    children: [
      Text('Your Order List'),
      Container(
        height: 300, // or any other number
        width: 300, // or any other number
        child: cartList(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: You are awesome.! It works.! Thank you so much, man.